# Debugging Azure Data Lake Analytics - Solution is not being created for a local debug vertex

Tags: visual-studio, azure, visual-studio-2015, azure-data-lake

As per the [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-lake-analytics/data-lake-analytics-debug-u-sql-jobs#debug-job-failed-with-assemblies) I have downloaded a vertex locally for debugging.
I'd like to debug an assembly that is related, however when I do this, Visual Studio does not create a solution, making it impossible to add my assembly project.

**Microsofts screenshot:**
[image: Screenshot from Microsoft]

**My Screenshot - note the missing solution**
[image: My screenshot of the missing solution]

Is there an easy way to add my assembly project to the LocalVertex?

Comment: Workaround was to manually edit the sln file. It turns out a .sln file was created but isn't displayed in VS. if you look at the properties on the "LocalVertexHost" - you can identify the folder. Inside the folder is a .sln file, which you can edit manually to add a project reference to the existing assembly project.

Answer (score 1):

If there's already a .sln file, you could try opening that instead of the project file as well.  In the latest version of the tools, the solution shows up automatically in the debug instance, and there is also a short `readme` file that contains some pointers as well.  You could try updating your Data Lake Tools for VS by downloading and installing the latest build.